# subprocess.call() is not waiting

Tags: python, time, subprocess

I'm using subprocess.call and I need to track the amount of time that it takes to execute. The documentation says that subprocess.call should block execution while the child process runs but the printed time() values are only a few miliseconds apart even if vlc has been running for minutes.

```
print time.time()
vlc = ['vlc', '--play-and-exit', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8Egrmm0GeE&list=PLRQGRBgN_EnrgJvnfr-q6zcPdvhBmjLRB']
subprocess.call(vlc)
print time.time()
```

I'm running this on Windows with Cygwin. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that `vlc` runs in some sort of daemon process.  If you try the command from the command line, does it block?

Comment: Looks like you called it! I'm gonna have to find another way to do this. Thanks!